# angular-material - open link in md-checkbox

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have this code:

```
<div layout="row">
  <md-checkbox aria-label="Checkbox">
            Read <a href="terms-of-service.pdf" target="_blank">terms&conditions</a>
  </md-checkbox>
</div>
```

How can I open link in "md-checkbox" ?

Here is [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xG4MIhOMvsQeiJITSOQk?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems to be a bug in angular-material, but you can go around it and use `pointer-events: all` as a style attribute.

try to change `<a href="terms-of-service.pdf" target="_blank">` to `<a href="terms-of-service.pdf" target="_blank" style="pointer-events: all">` - it works for me in your plunk.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be a [known bug](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/852).
But was [fixed](https://github.com/angular/material/commit/999e0da21f2ae39526ec2d40b94452b8fa865465) 5 days ago in the v.0.10

Try with this new version to get the bug fixed.

```
<link data-require="angular-material@0.10.0-rc4" data-semver="0.10.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/0.10.0-rc4/angular-material.min.css" />
<script data-require="angular-material@0.10.0-rc4" data-semver="0.10.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/0.10.0-rc4/angular-material.min.js"></script>
```

See it here : http://plnkr.co/edit/fjXDqbi6U5p6zv9K1AKM?p=preview